# Can a broken CF card break a camera?

Tags: dslr, troubleshooting, cfcard

I recently made a stupid mistake of putting a broken CF card back into my Canon 350D. The result of this was that now the camera only shows "no CF" on the LCD, but refuses to do anything else. No reaction to any buttons, no CF-reader LED flashing.

About the broken CF card: this one must have been short-circuited when plugging it into my card reader while still humid. The reader instantly turned hot.

I've of course tried to remove all batteries, the lens, the CF card (put in another).

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Yes, a physically broken card can break a camera ([see my new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83314/pin-in-cf-card-slot-bent-any-way-to-fix-that-myself)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have removed the card from the camera and put a new one in (that is known to be good) then it sounds like you already have your answer.

It is possible that the card (rather than the reader) was shorted out and that it damaged the reader both on the computer and in the camera.  If that is the case, then there is a good chance you need to have the card reader and possibly system board replaced in the camera.

Your best bet is probably to contact Canon to see about what a repair would cost and either send it in for service or buy a new (or used) camera since the 350D is now pretty old and may well not be worth repairing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After some research it seems the two Canon repair centres in my country don't support the 350D anymore. I think I'll use the chance to re-evaluate my whole camera system (Canon EF-S), which I wanted to do anyway.

Comment: Do be sure to also look at the newer Canon cameras. The 350 is a very old model and a ton of improvements (live view, video, video focusing, wifi support, etc) have come out since then. I'm biased as a long time fan and user of Canon gear, but they do make really solid gear for the price though they are not always the cheapest on the block.